# python: concatenate integer items in a list to a single string

Tags: python, join, char, int

Is there a better way of the following for concatenating items in a list that are "integers" into a string:

```
import numpy as np
my_list = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
changed_list = np.char.mod('%d', my_list)
final_ans = ''.join(changed_list )
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it gives me the error "name 'string' is not defined". Btw I am using python 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean by better, but you could try this.

```
''.join([str(x) for x in my_list])
```

Comment: Why repost an answer that's been posted 2 minutes ago already?

Comment: Because I hadnt refreshed the page.

Answer (score 6):

how about this?

```
''.join([str(item) for item in my_list])
```

Comment: I think you mean 'for item in my_list' (not my changed_list)!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`bitstring`](https://pypi.org/project/bitstring/) module:

```
>>> from bitstring import BitArray
>>> f'{BitArray(my_list).uint:b}'
'110000111010'
```